# Accessing a member in a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

If I have the following struct:

```
struct myStruct {
    int value;
    struct myStruct *next;
};
```

and have an instance delcared as

```
struct myStruct *the_struct = (void *) malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct))
```

How do I access the "value" of *next?

I have tried doing

```
the_struct->next.value
```

and

```
*(the_struct->next)->value
```

but I receive error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type."

Comment: [In C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about accessing struct members via a pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405537/confused-about-accessing-struct-members-via-a-pointer)

Comment: the second one `(*the_struct->next).value` is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
 the_struct->next->value
```

but before that, you should be sure that `the_struct->next` is valid.

BTW, [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) does fail, and it gives an *uninitialized* memory zone on success. So read also [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) and [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html), then code:

```
struct myStruct *the_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
if (!the_struct) 
  { perror("malloc myStruct"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
the_struct->value = -1;
the_struct->next = NULL;
```

(Alternatively, zero every byte of a *successful* result of `malloc` with [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html), or use `calloc` instead of  `malloc`).

Later on, you might likewise get and initialize a `struct myStruct* next_struct` and finally assign `the_struct->next = next_struct;` and after that you could e.g. assign `the_struct->next->value = 32;` (or, in that particular case, the equivalent `next_struct->value = 32;`)

Please compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`). On Linux, use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).